# how to conditionally store command line variable inside function without getting illegal instruction4?

Tags: c

Assuming the input could be either `./test -v abc.txt` or `./test abc.txt`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char *filename = argv[1];
    bool verbose = false;
    handleCommandLine(argv, filename, &verbose);
  
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
```

```
void handleCommandLine(char *argv[], char *filename, bool *verbose)
{

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-v") == 0)
    {
        printf("initialize\n");
        *verbose = true;
        strcpy(filename, argv[2]); <===== this gets illegal instruction4 when I execute 
    }
  
}
```

when I execute `./test -v test abc.txt`, I get illegal instruction4
Can someone help ? Thank you

Comment: How about checking `argc` first? Also `filename` is just a pointer (that seems to be first pointing to `argv[1]`, but then you are copying `argv[2]` into it - which you can't do).

Comment: In the first example usage you provide, `argv[1]` is `"-v"` which is a char array of length 3, and `argv[2]` is `"abc.txt"` which is a char array with length 8.  Even if the compiler doesn't stop you from copying into that memory, you'll end up with a buffer overflow using `strcpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments already answered why you were getting an error.  Here is working implementation:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void handleCommandLine(int argc, char **argv, char **filename, bool *verbose) {
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if(!strcmp(argv[i], "-v")) {
            *verbose = 1;
            // skip "test" arg to -v?
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        // filename will be the last argument
        *filename = argv[i];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *filename = NULL;
    bool verbose = false;
    handleCommandLine(argc, argv, &filename, &verbose);
    printf("filename=%s, verbose=%d\n", filename, verbose);
    return 0;
}
```

and here some test output (as /usr/bin/test is a thing, consider using a better name for your program):

```
./test -v
filename=(null), verbose=1
./test -v test abc.txt
filename=abc.txt, verbose=1
./test abc.txt
filename=abc.txt, verbose=0
```